# Refused to display 'http://vimeo.com/27577981' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: javascript, video, embed

I am trying to embed a video in embed tag But I am getting this error :

```
Refused to display 'http://vimeo.com/27577981' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

for youtube link : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBEYR69o2Ao
when i replace watch?v= with embed/ , it runs fine. But its is not necessary that video will be of youtube. So I want a unique solution for this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As the error message says, you can't embed that page in a frame. Vimeo [provide documentation on how to embed their player](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding). Follow that.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>{page_title}</title>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{video_id}" width="{video_width}" height="{video_height}" frameborder="0" title="{video_title}" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But this is specific solution for above URL. In my scenario, URL can be any public video URl..In that case, What will be possible solution

Comment: You take the video id from the url and put it into the format accepted by their embedding rules.

Comment: What is the embedding rules for running a a video. I am new To HTML, sp help me to find this solution.

Comment: @Rishi — They are documented on Vimeo's site. I linked to them.

Comment: I understand you point but I am asking for that video URL which is not vimeo like http://espn.go.com/video/clip?id=9471186&categoryid=2378529 . In this URL how will i add embedding rules for this

Comment: There is no magic way to find an acceptable means to embed any arbitrary URL. You need to handle each video provider on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: In this case it is helpful to know that Vimeo stopped allowing embeds via addresses like //vimeo.com/84831861  and now insists on format //player.vimeo.com/video/84831861

Comment: The posted url redirects to another address, which was very helpful too: `https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed`

Answer (score 31):

I had the similiar problem
solution:
in short (at the moment) the embed url is:

```
//player.vimeo.com/video/
```

instead of:

```
//vimeo.com/27577981
```

for instance:

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/27577981?portrait=0" class="ivid" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but as Quentin said check the vimeo documentation: http://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding

Answer (score 1):

Ruby String Manipulation to get functioning links (2020.09.01) based on @Picard https://stackoverflow.com/a/27039766/12839228 and @basarat https://stackoverflow.com/a/51976196/12839228:

**Youtube Example:**

```
raw_video_link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qap5aO4i9A&ab_channel=ChilledCow'
video_link = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + raw_video_link.split('=')[1].split('&')[0]
```

**Vimeo Example:**

```
raw_video_link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ'.split('/')
  insert_player_link = raw_video_link[2].split('.').unshift('player').join('.')
  raw_video_link.delete_at(2)
  raw_video_link.insert(2, insert_player_link)
  raw_video_link.insert(3, 'video')
  video_link = raw_video_link.join('/')
```

Feel free to refactor!

Answer (score 0):

this is happening due to the website in the iframe is setting the X-Frame-Options  header to: SAMEORIGIN

The only way to make this work is to get the web-site to either not set the header or to change the value to ALLOW-FROM your-uri

This is why you need to follow the Vimeo instructions to get it working, but obviously every site has to be treated independently.

This policy is a security measure to avoid click hijacking. You can check more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options