# Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKZRsBjQJOs' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, pipe

I need to place a video from youtube in my website but the URL is a variable, I created a pipe to can put, but don't work.

This is my code in HTML file

```html
<iframe width="670" height="348" [src]=" video | video" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

the code of my pipe is this

```js
export class VideoPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor (private domSanitizer:DomSanitizer ){ }

    transform(url: string): any {
        return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl( url );
    }

}
```

but when I tried to put the video URL , I get the error.

I asign the URL video in a switch case

```js
case 'marketing':{
              this.bodyClass="background-marketing-text";
              this.btnClass="btnMarketing";
              this.video="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTyFV-qhQtQ";
              break;
          }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change your url `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTyFV-qhQtQ` to `https://www.youtube.com/embed/TTyFV-qhQtQ`

## Reason

`/embed` has the required header.

## Why is `X-Frame-Options`

It is there for user security. Prevents `clickjacking` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

The `embed` endpoint is desinged to be safer to show on external websites (not `youtube.com`).